# Javascript: prevent dropdown open when selecting

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I want to prevent that a dropdown menu is opened when selecting a range of cells.
I know, I can add an `onmousedown` event and call `event.preventDefault()`

The problem is that this will disable the dropdown for a single click event too. Is there a way to distinguish between the selection of a range (the mouse is pressed and not immediately released) and the click on a single cell (mouse is pressed and released)?
I have also tried with `onselectstart` but it doesn't help me in this case.

Here a small demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/vqsv99t4/2/

Comment: **[Check the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139860/2065039)**

Comment: Thx, but my real case is a little more complex. The selection can start in any cell of a table. This cell could be a combobox, but also a date input picker, or a text input. So it would be complex to implement the solution you suggested (I hope there is an easier way ;)

Comment: @Zardo can you please share your code? so that we can understand what you have achieved. Then maybe we can help you better.

Comment: Well, in that case it would be easier if you provide some `demo` for it to help you.. :)

Comment: Here the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vqsv99t4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code to work according to your need.

1. **Disable text selection**: Removed from Javascript to CSS

   ```css
   .noselect {
     -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
       -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
        -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
          -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
           -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
               user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                     not supported by any browser */
   }
   ```

   Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/1957036
2. **Stopping event bubble from `<td>` to `document`**: `event.stopPropagation()` will stop bubbling up the event to document `mousemove()` and `mouseup()` listener
3. **Logic**: Storing the first cell from which the selection has started (`mousedown()` event on the cell). Then, checking the cell where the selection has stopped(`mouseup()` event).
4. Modified HTML for better usage.
5. Added `data-` attribute on cells for storing row-column information

**Updated-2016-11-11**

6. Added jQuery-UI [`Selectmenu`](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) to replace `<select>`.

   > **Reason**: `<select>` dropdown can't be triggered using JavaScript/JQuery.

```js
//console.clear();

var BUTTON_LEFT = 1,
  BUTTON_RIGHT = 2;

var startCell = null;


(function() {

  $("#select").selectmenu();

  $(".mouse-event-cell")
    .on('mousedown', onMouseDown)
    .on('mouseup', onMouseUp)
    .on('mousemove', onMouseOver);
  $(document)
    .on('mousemove', onDocMouseOver)
    .on('mouseup', onDocMouseUp);
})();

function onDocMouseOver(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== BUTTON_LEFT) {
    startCell = null;
    clearFill();
  }
}

function onDocMouseUp(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== BUTTON_LEFT) {
    startCell = null;
    clearFill();
  }
}

function onMouseDown(e) {
  isInsideCell = true;

  if (startCell === null)
    startCell = e.currentTarget;
};

function onMouseOver(e) {
  if (startCell !== null) {
    fill(startCell, e.currentTarget, 'region');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
  var endCell = e.currentTarget;

  if (startCell !== null) {
    fill(startCell, endCell, 'selected');
  }

  startCell = null;
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function fill(startCell, endCell, classToAdd) {
  var col0 = startCell.dataset['column'],
    row0 = startCell.dataset['row'],
    col1 = endCell.dataset['column'],
    row1 = endCell.dataset['row'],
    colMin = Math.min(col0, col1),
    colMax = Math.max(col0, col1),
    rowMin = Math.min(row0, row1),
    rowMax = Math.max(row0, row1);

  clearFill();

  if (startCell === endCell) {
    console.log('same-cell');
  } else {
    console.log('range-of-cell');
  }

  //console.log(startCell, endCell);


  for (var itCol = colMin; itCol <= colMax; itCol++) {
    for (var itRow = rowMin; itRow <= rowMax; itRow++) {
      $('#codexpl .mouse-event-cell#cell_' + itRow + '_' + itCol).addClass(classToAdd);
    }
  }
}

function clearFill() {
  $('#codexpl .mouse-event-cell').removeClass('selected').removeClass('region');
}
```

```css
.ui-selectmenu-button.ui-button {
  width: 5em;
}
select {
  width: auto;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
td.mouse-event-cell {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  height: 30px;
  /*To disable the text selection*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
td.selected {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white;
}
td.region {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: #BBB;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="selecting multiple cells">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="codexpl">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Columna</th>
      <th>Relative</th>
      <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell_0_0" data-row="0" data-column="0" class='mouse-event-cell'>
        <select id="select">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="cell_0_1" data-row="0" data-column="1" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[0][1]</td>
      <td id="cell_0_2" data-row="0" data-column="2" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[0][2]</td>
      <td id="cell_0_3" data-row="0" data-column="3" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[0][3]</td>
      <td id="cell_0_4" data-row="0" data-column="4" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[0][4]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell_1_0" data-row="1" data-column="0" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[1][0]</td>
      <td id="cell_1_1" data-row="1" data-column="1" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[1][1]</td>
      <td id="cell_1_2" data-row="1" data-column="2" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[1][2]</td>
      <td id="cell_1_3" data-row="1" data-column="3" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[1][3]</td>
      <td id="cell_1_4" data-row="1" data-column="4" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[1][4]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell_2_0" data-row="2" data-column="0" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[2][0]</td>
      <td id="cell_2_1" data-row="2" data-column="1" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[2][1]</td>
      <td id="cell_2_2" data-row="2" data-column="2" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[2][2]</td>
      <td id="cell_2_3" data-row="2" data-column="3" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[2][3]</td>
      <td id="cell_2_4" data-row="2" data-column="4" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[2][4]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell_3_0" data-row="3" data-column="0" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[3][0]</td>
      <td id="cell_3_1" data-row="3" data-column="1" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[3][1]</td>
      <td id="cell_3_2" data-row="3" data-column="2" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[3][2]</td>
      <td id="cell_3_3" data-row="3" data-column="3" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[3][3]</td>
      <td id="cell_3_4" data-row="3" data-column="4" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[3][4]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell_4_0" data-row="4" data-column="0" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[4][0]</td>
      <td id="cell_4_1" data-row="4" data-column="1" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[4][1]</td>
      <td id="cell_4_2" data-row="4" data-column="2" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[4][2]</td>
      <td id="cell_4_3" data-row="4" data-column="3" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[4][3]</td>
      <td id="cell_4_4" data-row="4" data-column="4" class='mouse-event-cell'>cell[4][4]</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I really appreciated the time you have invested for me. Very nice solution, but this doesn't solve my problem: if I add the mouse-cell-event class even to the combobox and I start the selection from this cell, the dropdown menu is displayed and the selection of a range become difficult.

Comment: Ohh. I think I now got the issue. I will update soon.

Comment: Btw a solution could be to make the combobox not editable, but this has the drawback that I should do a selection-mode and a non-selection-mode. It would be nice if I could avoid this....

Comment: @Zardo Don't fear...I am here. I will resolve this. :)  

Comment: @Zardo I have updated the code as `<select>` was not working acc to our needs. I hope above solution will work for you. Let me know even still if there are some issues.

Comment: Wow, cool! Now it's working exactly as i wish! Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Its awesome if it really helped you. :)

Comment: can I ask another question? You have marked with the css class "mouse-event-cell" all cell that have listeners for mouse events and than with a javascript function you set the real listeners. Is this approach better than setting onMouseOver, onMouseDown,... on every cell? I understand it keeps the xhtml page more compact... can this influence the performance of loading the page as well?

Comment: @Zardo Unfortunately, yes, it will affect the performance as we are attaching listener to each cell.

Comment: @Zardo Refer to this SO Ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627606/does-adding-too-many-event-listeners-affect-performance