# JS Event delegation with the same function reference

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about event delegation, and I understand that if I am creating something like the following, it could be expensive for memory.

```
bigElementsArray.addEventListener("click", e => {

});
```

But, what if I am pointing to the same function in memory, this will create only one handler.

```
const sameFunctionRef = e => {};
bigElementsArray.addEventListener("click", sameFunctionRef);
```

So, why this is a problem, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aside:** In your first code snippet I assume you're iterating over an array and adding event listeners (I'm happy to be corrected, but I'm not aware of a way without some JS trickery of adding event listeners to an array of elements).

The issue here isn't creating a bunch of new functions (that is *an* issue), but creating a bunch of event listeners. Having a bunch of event listeners is expensive because as the browser needs to maintain them all and you need to be sure to remove the event listeners if elements get deleted to avoid memory leaks.

A better approach is to use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). The basic idea is take advantage of event bubbling and have a single event handler on a parent element which then takes action depending on the event target.

Related is this answer which demonstrates the performance tradeoffs well: [Does adding too many event listeners affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627606/does-adding-too-many-event-listeners-affect-performance)