# Is adding/removing new event listeners with window.addEventListener expensive?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

Is it really expensive to add and remove event listeners when they are needed or is it much better to just set them once?

For example, I have modalA and modalB. If modalA is open, I really only need to know when I click outside of modalA to close it. If I have the event listener alway added to both, it will fire modalB's `close` function even though it's not open.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like code that needs optimising. Is it a bottleneck? If not, then just do whatever is most convenient to write and maintain.

Comment: Was just curious because `getBoundingClientRect` is expensive

Comment: Depends on how it's used but, generally, no. In my opinion, orphan memory leaks are more of a concern. Unless you are hammering the browser or a potential bottleneck (very helpful - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) you typically don't need to worry about it.

Comment: That is an entirely different and wholly incomparable operation, though. `getFibonacciNumber(999999)` is also going to be expensive, but I don't think that would affect, say, `console.log`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does adding too many event listeners affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627606/does-adding-too-many-event-listeners-affect-performance)

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer depends on the scale of your application.

If it's small (you can control the amount of places you do it), then it is probably OK.

If it's big (enterprise) or you are creating a library to be used as infrastructure, you better add and remove the listener. (for example if 100 dialogs are on screen, every click on the screen will trigger all 100 listeners, it can hurt performance on a large scale)