# How does multiple listeners for the same window events affect performance?

Tags: javascript, browser

In a web project I'm using multiple listeners for the same window events.

```js
window.addevntlistener("resize", callback)
window.addevntlistener("hasChange", callback)
```

I assume adding multiple event listeners on the window has a negligible effect in terms of performance. Is it so, or should I just listen once, and add a my own javascript subscribing solution for the various units which need to be notified?

The resize listener could be used by a basic UI element which is rendered in a list, and therefor add hundreds of listeners.

**Edit:** 
I'm aware of [Does adding too many event listeners affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627606/does-adding-too-many-event-listeners-affect-performance) . However, that refers to a element click events. In that case there are multiple listeners to multiple objects. In my case there are multiple listeners to the same object, and a special object - the window.

Comment: If you need to listen for multiple events, there's basically no alternative *other* than to call `addEventListener` multiple times. But don't worry about performance unless you've actually run a performance test and something turns out to be taking too many resources

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does adding too many event listeners affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627606/does-adding-too-many-event-listeners-affect-performance)

Comment: @jeprubio, no it doesn't. That refers to a element click events. In that case there are listeners on multiple objects. In my case it is multiple listeners to the same object, and a special object - the window.

Comment: You will need to write a test to confirm this but I've seen too many listeners added to one object become unresponsive. I believe it was on Chrome.

Comment: @SILENT, what do you mean by one object? Was it a dom object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Javascript you have an [event loop](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/). The mechanism consists of a loop, which represents the plan to call certain functions in a given order. However, user event, such as click or resize cannot be planned before it happens. As a result, there is also a message queue (also called callback queue), where your events are waiting to be executed.

[image]

When the event queue runs out of functions to be executed, the message queue's items start to be processed. At this point your events will be processed.

Basically we are talking of a forever loop where you put some functions. Of course it affects performance, because everything to be done affects the performance versus the case when it is not done. However, this in most cases does not mean a meaningful difference in any way that could be felt.

If we assume that the functions you associate with these events is of very low (maybe constant) complexity, then we still have a linear complexity due to the event loop and you would have to add MANY events to this loop to have any performance difference that could be felt.

However, if the functions that you add are very complex, that will significantly decrease performance and note, Javascript is (mostly) single-threaded. So, if you experience performance issues, then you need to check the complexity of your functions first.

It is worth noting that your event handlers will only be executed when the given event is triggered, probably by the user. So, if you add a million of resize handlers, by themselves they will not affect performance (except at the time when they are added, but that's insignificant), but when a resize happens, all your event handlers attached to this event will be executed.

So, if you experience performance issues at a given event, then you will need to analyze the event handlers associated to that event. If your event handlers are too many or too complex, then you can use [web workers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) (which are running in separate threads) to execute the more time-consuming jobs, so your UI will remain responsive in terms of handling events.

EDIT

This is how one can test the two scenarios. In this code we will assume that `event` is a `String` variable, which can be a click, a key event or anything.

## Measurement functionality

```
var count = 1000; //you can change this value whenever you need
var startDate;
var endDate;
var diff;

function happened() {
    if (!startDate) startDate = performance.now();
    if (!(--count)) {
        endDate = performance.now();
        diff = endDate - startDate; //in milliseconds
        console.log(diff);
    }
}
```

## Many Listeners

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) window.addEventListener("resize", function() {happened()});
```

61 milliseconds in my test (event was "resize" in my case)

## Single listener

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    while (count > 0) happened();
});
```

55 milliseconds in my test (event was "resize" in my case)

Comment: This is excellent, but in terms of 1) performance and 2) code, how does multiple independent listerners to the same event compare with a single listerner, and javascript subscribing method that notifies the various units?

Comment: @BenCarp The difference in terms of performance is that in the case when there are many listeners they will be on the message loop and will wait for the event loop to execute the scheduled functions first. Theoretically there should be no difference in performance. In practice this depends on the actual implementation of Javascript. The best way to test is to have many listeners on the same event and measure their execution time and alternatively, to have a single event calling functions.

Comment: @BenCarp in code the difference is that in one case you add event listeners, in the others you call functions inside an event listener. I have edited my answer to give you more information.

Comment: I have seen that both the question and this answer was downvoted. Are there any known issues to improve?

Comment: Your test excellently demonstrate my concern. While your results were not significant for count=1000, for a higher count value the gap is significant. For count=50000 it was about 40 times slower on average. While such a high number will not occur in reality, it does demonstrate that the callback que is an expensive way to run a loop, and handling it within JS is better.

Comment: @BenCarp interesting. This means that the implementation(s) of Javascript you have tested at have a subpar performance in this case. If so, then the problem might cease to exist in future versions.

Comment: My test was executed in latest Chrome. The test you run showed negligible difference, while the tests I ran showed significant difference. I think this could be relevant to your answer. Perhaps you can rerun the  test on Chrome with peformance.now and update the results.

Comment: Lajos, I awarded you with the bounty points because your answer is excellent. But since you requested feedback ("Are there any known issues to improve?"), I do think it could be shortened. Anyway, thanks for your help.