# How to share a single MUI useScrollTrigger return value among multiple components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

I am currently using MUI's `useScrollTrigger` hook to determine the appearance of three components - `NavBar`, a post FAB a back to top button e.g.:

```
export default function NavBar() {
  const isScrolledDown = useScrollTrigger({ target: window, threshold: 100 });
  return (
    <>
      <Slide in={!isScrolledDown} >
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Slide>
      <Toolbar />
      <BackToTopFAB isScrolledDown={isScrolledDown} />
      <PostCreateFAB isScrolledDown={isScrolledDown} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Since I do not want to make the browser listen for three separate "scroll" events, I am currently drilling the hook's return value from the `NavBar` into the two buttons.

However, as a result, I am unable to decouple the two buttons from the `NavBar`.

Does anyone have any suggestions how this may be possible, so that all three components share the same hook return value? If having multiple "scroll" listeners is not DOM-intensive, I am also willing to consider that

Answer (score 0):

React hook is designed to be reusable, you probably want to move the `useScrollTrigger` hook to the components that need it like below:

```
const useCustomScrollTrigger = () => useScrollTrigger({ target: window, threshold: 100 });

const BackToTopFAB = () => {
  const isScrolledDown = useCustomScrollTrigger();
  return (...)
}

const PostCreateFAB = () => {
  const isScrolledDown = useCustomScrollTrigger();
  return (...)
}

const MyAppBar = () => {
  const isScrolledDown = useCustomScrollTrigger();
  return (
    <Slide in={!isScrolledDown} >
      <AppBar />
    </Slide>
  )
}

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyAppBar />
      <OtherContent />
      <BackToTopFAB />
      <PostCreateFAB />
    </>
  );
}
```

Doing so has a couple of advantages:

- Your code is easier to read because the logic is hidden away in each specific component. Code readability is one of the most important factors when choosing between trade-offs IMO. Several additional event listeners should never impact your application performance in any way.
- Improve your the performance of the parent component since there is no props at the top-level component, if the `isScrolledDown` state is changed, only 3 isolated components are re-rendered as a result. Otherwise, other components in the page like `OtherContent` also need to be rendered because the state in the parent component changes.

You can also have a look at some react state management libraries like [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) if you want to store the state in a single place and access it anywhere in the components regardless of its position in the hierarchy:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const { actions } = createSlice({
  name: 'globalState',
  initialState: { isScrolledDown: false },
  reducers: {
    setIsScrolledDown: (state, action) => {
      state.isScrolledDown = action.payload
    },
  },
})
```

```
const ScrollLisenter = () => {
  const isScrolledDown = useScrollTrigger({ /* ... */ });
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.setIsScrolledDown(isScrolledDown));
  }, [isScrolledDown]);

  return null
}

const BackToTopFAB = () => {
  const isScrolledDown = useSelector(state => state.globalState.isScrolledDown);
  return (...)
}

const PostCreateFAB = () => {
  const isScrolledDown = useSelector(state => state.globalState.isScrolledDown);
  return (...)
}
```

```
<App>
  <ScrollLisenter />
  <NavBar />
</App>
```

### Related Question

- [Does adding too many event listeners affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627606/does-adding-too-many-event-listeners-affect-performance)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! I will follow your advice :)